# Counting number of duplicate occurrences [R]

Tags: r, dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('black','black','black','red','red'),
                 type=c('chair','chair','sofa','sofa','sofa'),
                 num=c(4,4,12,4,6))
```

For each row, I want to count the number of times that "type" appears with that row's num value, and then create a new column. So for the first row, "chair" and "num" appears twice in the dataset, so it gets assigned a 2. For the second row, same thing. For the 3rd row, sofa appears once with a value of 12.

```
df
#    name  type num count
# 1 black chair   4     2
# 2 black chair   4     2
# 3 black  sofa  12     1
# 4   red  sofa   4     1
# 5   red  sofa   6     1
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code to create the df: the second `num` should be `4`.

Comment: Same assignment 5 years and 10 months later..;)

Answer (score 7):

Using `ave` in base R, you have

```
df$count <- with(df, ave(num, name, type, num, FUN=length))
```

Get the length of num, grouping by name, type, and num. Use `with` to reduce typing a bit.

this returns

```
df
   name  type num count
1 black chair   4     2
2 black chair   4     2
3 black  sofa  12     1
4   red  sofa   4     1
5   red  sofa   6     1
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `dplyr::add_count`:

```
dplyr::add_count(df, type, num)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
#    name   type   num     n
#  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <int>
#1  black  chair     4     2
#2  black  chair     4     2
#3  black   sofa    12     1
#4    red   sofa     4     1
#5    red   sofa     6     1
```